# Converting time/date from XML file into MYSQL format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

One of the affiliate networks provides a feed with the following time/date format.

```
<startDate>1349992800000</startDate>
<endDate>1355266799999</endDate>
```

My problem is I am trying to convert this to a MYSQL format, I have tried mktime and strtotime with no luck the date seems to come out wrong. I know this is the time since the Equinox, I am just not sure how to convert this to a MYSQL format.

Comment: That Equinox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox ? And what is the unit of measurement? Seconds?

Comment: I imagine the OP meant "[UNIX] [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let MySQL do the conversion using [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (`startDate`, `endDate`)
VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME( 1349992800000 ), FROM_UNIXTIME( 1355266799999 ) );
```

You may have to divide by 1000 first, as your timestamp seems to milliseconds since epoch, while MySQL uses seconds since epoch.

Comment: Perfect thanks, wasn't working and then I realised I had not divided by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

This datetimes are [timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp)

If you go through php, in the date function manual page ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) you can see that you can create a date object from the format and timestamp

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

try it,

good luck!